# Can't understand android layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to create a main menu on my app and currently all I know how to use is absolute layout which seems to be really bad for different screen sizes. I've tried all different layouts using tables and linear and relative layout and I just can't get it to be the same. I know it's a basic enough question but I've tried everything and it doesn't seem to work. here's what I want it to look like:
[image: Any chance someone could give me a hint even as to the best method to approach this? Thanks]

Comment: It appears like just being a standard GridView in a Linear or RelativeLayout...

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` is depreceted. Use `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or a custom layout instead.

Comment: I think good is to use horizontal linear layout with weight and inside put gridview. In lanscape folder you can set grid for 3 items and size of grid will be set by linear layout weight

Comment: @janhruska in portrait mode, the layout has to be vertical. Horizontal is appropriate for landscape mode. Weights aren't needed here. Please don't suggest using unneeded features, since they can harm performances.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Grid View](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)**

> Android GridView shows items in two-dimensional scrolling grid (rows &
>   columns) and the grid items are not necessarily predetermined but they
>   automatically inserted to the layout using a ListAdapter .

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html